# <ul> causes neighbouring div to fall

Tags: html, css

When you uncomment the unordered list tag the second container div falls a bit down. If you actually could explain me why this is happening and told me how to remove this behavior I would be thankful.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(38, 48, 90);
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> Depr </h1>
  <!--<ul>
        <li>Derping</li>
        <li>Derping</li>
      </ul>-->
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1> Derpina</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason behind why this occurs is, when you make any element to be `inline-block`, it aligns to baseline by default. So, when the heights of all elements are not same, it gets scrambled and aligned to their baseline. This is the main problem with all the `inline-block` and we should correct it by giving the right vertical alignment. To do that, please follow the below snippet:

I found your issue to be vertical alignment. Just give:

```css
.container {
  vertical-align: middle;   /* This */
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 
    0.24);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(38, 48, 90);
}
```

**Preview**

Without the `<ul>` and with it:

[image: preview]

**JSBin: http://jsbin.com/zalagixovu/edit?output**

Comment: @BillyRay Can you recheck, please?

Comment: @BillyRay Welcome! That's what I wrote... `:)`

Comment: He asked for an explanation of why this is happening. Why does this fix the problem?